# Regularity or non-regularity of union of two languages

Tags: regular-languages

Consider this language:

$K=\{xy \mid x=\{a,b\}^*, y=x^R \text{ or } y=x\}$

I know that these languages are non-regular separately:

$K_1=\{xy \mid x=\{a,b\}^*, y=x^R\}$

$K_2=\{xy \mid x=\{a,b\}^*, y=x\}$

But what about their union?

Comment: There's no rule as such. Provide a DFA/NFA to prove or use the pumping lemma to disprove.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose towards a contradiction that $w$ is regular, let $p$ be its pumping length, and consider the word: $a^pba^pb \in w$.

By the pumping lemma, there is some $k \ge 1$ such that $a^{p + ik}b a^p b \in w$ for all choices of an integer $i \ge -1$. Choosing $i=-1$ we obtain $a^{p-k}b a^p b \in w$. This is a contradiction, therefore $w$ is not regular.